# Hashing gives different result

Tags: python, mysql, hash, salt, hashlib

I am using Python and MySql to handle user authentication. I have added the users thru python with the exact same method, but when I try to do the "login"/authentication it does not match.

This is my code for authentication:

```
# Collecting data from users. 
username=data['username']
password=data['password']

cur=mysql.connection.cursor()

# Checks if username exists. 
check_username = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=%s",[username])

if check_username > 0:

     # Retrieves the correct salt of the user.
     cur.execute("SELECT `salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=%s",[username])
     get_salt = cur.fetchone()

     # Generates the hashed password of the user. 
     hashed_password=(hashlib.sha256((str(password[0:2])+str(get_salt[0])+str(password[2:])).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()).lower()

     # Retrieves the hashed password of the user from the database. 
     cur.execute("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=%s",[username])
     get_password = cur.fetchone()

     # Checks if identical.
     if get_password[0] == hashed_password:

          return jsonify("Authentication successful!"),201

     else: return jsonify("Authentication failed!"),401

else: return 'Incorrect username. Please try again.'
```

The hashed_password does not return the same hashed password that is stored in the database.

And this is the code I used to insert the users.

```
username=data['username']
password=data['password']
salt=data['salt']

cur=mysql.connection.cursor()

# Generates the hashed password of the user. 
hashed_password=(hashlib.sha256((str(password[0:2])+str(salt[0])+str(password[2:])).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()).lower() 

# Adds user to database.
add_user = cur.execute(" INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `salt`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);",[username,hashed_password, salt])
```

Does anyone see what is causing this?

Comment: Looks to me like you are asking a user to provide their own salt. Not goo idea, the slat will not be worth having as it wont have enough entropy

Comment: You can get all the columns from the user table using just One query rather than multiple queries to pluck single columns, very wasteful of network resourses, the slowest resource you will be using anywhere in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the insertion code, you seem to treat `salt` like the `get_salt` tuple, get first item, not knowing what it is originally, that might be the source of your issues as I would not expect the first salt you get to be in a tuple.

Here is a version that works, it's using SQLite rather than MySQL, but the changes are minimal besides formatting.

Also, I recommend you use [`hashlib.hash.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update) rather than your large and complicated one step hashing. And by default hexdigest is lowercase, so no need to `.lower()` it.

```py
# db setup
import hashlib
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE users (username TEXT, salt TEXT, password TEXT)")

in_username = "ljmc"
in_salt = "verysecuresalt"
in_password = "p4assW0rD1!"

h = hashlib.sha256()
h.update(str(in_password[:2]).encode("utf-8"))
h.update(str(in_salt).encode("utf-8"))  # here salt[0] is just b"v" not the whole salt
h.update(str(in_password[2:]).encode("utf-8"))
in_hashed_password = h.hexdigest()

cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    (in_username, in_salt, in_hashed_password), # then store whole salt
)

con.commit()

# user check
username = in_username
password = good_password

# Checks if username exists.
check_username = cur.execute(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ?", [username]
).fetchone()

if check_username[0] > 0:

    # Retrieves the correct salt of the user.
    cur.execute("SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username=?", [username])
    get_salt = cur.fetchone() # get the whole salt

    # Generates the hashed password of the user.
    hashed_password = (
        hashlib.sha256(
            (str(password[0:2]) + str(get_salt[0]) + str(password[2:])).encode(
                "utf-8"
            )
        ).hexdigest()
    ).lower() # use the whole salt

    # Retrieves the hashed password of the user from the database.
    cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?", [username])
    get_password = cur.fetchone()

    # Checks if identical.
    if get_password[0] == hashed_password:
        print("Authentication successful!")
    else:
        print("Authentication failed!")
```

As pointed out by other comments, it would also be a lot better to fetch all the user data in one query and then apply the logic, so the check block would look like this.

```py
cur.execute(
    "SELECT username, salt, password FROM users WHERE username = ?",
    (username,),
)

if user := cur.fetchone():
    out_username, out_salt, out_password = user

    h = hashlib.sha256()
    h.update(str(password[:2]).encode("utf-8"))
    h.update(str(out_salt).encode("utf-8"))
    h.update(str(password[2:]).encode("utf-8"))
    print(f"is the password {password} ?", out_password == h.hexdigest())
```